# Why ListView updates only if scrolled on device, but works fine on virtual device?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview

I recently started learning android development (am new to java as well) and I am currently working on a chat/messenger application

The problem I am facing, as the title says, is that the listview in which the messages are shown does not update on the device, unless scrolled, but it works fine on the virtual machine. I only tested on `LG Optimus l5 II` so far, but i need to fix this anyway.

I think it has something to do with multithreading, because this didn't happen until i added some new threads, so the adapter for listview, android manifest and rest I say are set up correctly. I can add them if it helps.

The 2 threads i added that might cause this:

1. Checks the connection status and if disconnected tries to reconnect.
2. The thread used for communicating with the server.

I tested running only with the second thread on, and the problem still occurs.

I want to specify this is the first time I try something like this (servers-client, multithreading, java, android (I'm still in college and they don`t teach us these kinds of stuff there) ), and had no documentation ahead regarding how I should set up the communication between the server and the client. This is the most efficient way I could think of.

this is at the end of `onCreate`:

```
StartConnectingRoutine(); // so you know where it all starts
```

and the code for it:

```
private void  StartConnectingRoutine()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    if(!connected)
                    {
                        if( connect != null)
                        {
                            if(!connect.isAlive())
                            {
                                ConnectListener();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ConnectListener();
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        sleep(CONNECTION_CHECK_TIME_MS); // this is set to 10000 (10 seconds)
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e("Intrerrupted", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

and the `connectListener()`:

```
private void ConnectListener()
{
    Log.d("Connecting", "Connecting...");
    connect = new Thread()
    {
        JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
        String receivedMessage;
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                info.put("Name", user.GetName());
                info.put("PORT", MY_PORT);
                info.put("IPv4", getIpAddress());
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                Log.e("JSON", "JSON error: " + e1.toString());
            }
            try
                {
                    ServerSocket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
                    dis = new DataInputStream(ServerSocket.getInputStream());
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(ServerSocket.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeUTF(info.toString());
                    dos.flush();
                    String response = dis.readUTF();
                    if(response.equals("connected"))
                            {
                                Log.d("Connect", "Connected!");
                                connected = true;
                            }
                        else
                            Log.d("Connect", "Failed to connect!");
                    while(connected)
                    {
                        receivedMessage = dis.readUTF();

                        DisplayNewMessage(new MMessage(receivedMessage, MMessage.MessageType.Received));                         
                    }

                }catch(SocketException e)
                {
                    try {
                        if(connected)
                        {   
                                ServerSocket.close();
                                dis.close();
                                dos.close();
                            connected = false;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("Connect", "Failed to connect");
                    Log.e("Connect", e.toString());
                    connected = false;
                }

        }
    };

    connect.start();
}
```

**Fixed:**

Reconnecting thread (i tried using asyncTask for this too, but it wouldn`t open the other asyncTask, even if I tried to open it from onProgressUpdate()-which it is supposed to be able to run ui thread components):

```
private void startConnectingRoutine()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread()
        {
            @Override 
            public void run()
            {
                Log.d("ConnectingRoutine", "Started connecting routine.");
                while(true)
                {
                    if(!connected)
                    {
                        startListener();
                    }
                    try {

                         sleep(CONNECTION_CHECK_TIME_MS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e("Intrerrupted", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

Listener thread:

```
private void startListener()
{
    new Listener().execute();
}
```

.

```
  private class Listener extends AsyncTask<Long, String, Long>
    {

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Long... params) {
            Log.d("Connecting...", "Connecting...");
            JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
            String receivedMessage;
                try {
                    info.put("Name", user.GetName());
                    info.put("PORT", MY_PORT);
                    info.put("IPv4", getIpAddress());
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    Log.e("JSON", "JSON error: " + e1.toString());
                }
                try
                    {
                        serverSocket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
                        dis = new DataInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream());
                        dos = new DataOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());

                        dos.writeUTF(info.toString());
                        dos.flush();
                        String response = dis.readUTF();
                        if(response.equals("connected"))
                                {
                                    Log.d("Connect", "Connected!");
                                    connected = true;
                                }
                            else
                                Log.d("Connect", "Failed to connect!");
                        while(connected)
                        {
                            receivedMessage = dis.readUTF();
                            publishProgress(receivedMessage);

                        }               
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.d("Connect", "Failed to connect");
                        Log.e("Connect", e.toString());
                        return null;
                    }
                   return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            displayNewMessage(new MMessage(values[0], MMessage.MessageType.Received));  
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            connected = false;
            try{
            if(serverSocket != null)
                serverSocket.close();
            if(dis != null)
                dis.close();
            if(dos != null)
                dos.close();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Listener", "There was a problem closing the connection: " + e.toString());
            }   
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Ok so I did the update and it now works fine. So the problem was #1. Paul Lammertsma said. Using the asyncTask, onProgressUpdate() fixed the problem. I'll add the code at the end of my question so others can see the problem and the answer in same place.

Comment: thank you again Paul Lammertsma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are perhaps multiple things going wrong here, but two that jump out are:

1. You're calling `DisplayNewMessage()` from outside the UI thread.
2. You're not notifying the adapter that its dataset has changed.

I urge you to look in to better mechanisms for executing tasks in the background than simply creating a Thread. Using AsyncTasks would be a good start, but you'll need to take special care to handle tasks between configuration changes (such as rotating the device).

Furthermore, your code is very difficult to read as you capitalize your method names. This is against Java code conventions. You will make things easier for yourself by formatting your code neatly (a good IDE helps with that) and learning to follow conventions!

Comment: the notifyDataSetChanged() is called in addItem() from adapter. I will start trying to follow the conventions. I have been coding in C# for quite some time and there we used capitalized function names. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I will try using AsyncTasks for the 2 threads as you said and I'll post an update when i finish.